# Telebot как боту получить id нового юзера

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, бот

Бот должен отслеживать заход\приглашение новых юзеров и сохранять их id. Я попробовал использовать хэндлер для отлова новых юзеров и сохранял message.new_chat_member.id, но оказалось, что у new_chat_member нету поля id, так как мне получить их id?

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["new_chat_members"])
def handler_new_member(message):
    print("New user!")
    user_id = message.new_chat_member.id
    print(user_id)
```

если просто использовать message.from_user.id, то будет выдавать id приглашающего, а не того, кого пригласили

Answer (score 0):

я понял, что message.new_chat_member это list, поэтому нужно брать элемент по индексу, тогда код будет выглядеть так:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["new_chat_members"])
def handler_new_member(message):
    print("New user!")
    user_id = message.new_chat_member[0].id
    print(user_id)
```